# Why is time complexity of `fun` $O(n)$?

Tags: algorithms, notation, asymptotics

Why is time complexity of `fun` $O(n)$?

```
int fun(int n)
{
  int count = 0;
  for (int i = n; i > 0; i /= 2)
     for (int j = 0; j < i; j++)
        count += 1;
  return count;
}
```

I think because of the nested loop it should be $O(n^2)$.

Comment: The outer loop is itself only about $log(n)$ steps, so even if the inner loop were going up to $n$ instead of up to $i$, the complexity would still only be $n \log(n)$. Since the inner loop is indeed going up to $i$, the complexity winds up not even being that much.

Comment: The inner loop does not go all the way up to $n$, but only to $i$. Not every time you have nested loops you have $O(n^2)$ complexity

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The inner (count += 1) operation is executed approximately $$n+\frac{n}{2}+\frac{n}{4}+\cdots=n\left(1+\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{4}+\cdots\right)=2n$$
times.

Answer (score 5):

The outer loop isn't looping through all linear values from n to 0. It is halving each time. So it goes: $n, \frac{n}{2}, \frac{n}{4}, \frac{n}{8}, \frac{n}{16}, ...$
The inner loop is called this many times so you need to work out $n+\frac{n}{2}+\frac{n}{4}+\frac{n}{8}+\frac{n}{16}+... = 2n$. Hence its $O(n)$.